# Proof that iteration of dividing in two halves gives 0 in limit.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume x is non-negative real number

$$\forall \varepsilon>0.\exists N\in \mathbb{N}.\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.n>N\to\frac{x}{2^n}<\varepsilon.$$

How to rigorously prove this statement from (maybe)induction and field/order/completeness axioms?

EDITED:
i find out that the task is impossible without Archimedian property:
"For an ordered field, Cauchy completeness is weaker than the other forms of completeness on this page. But Cauchy completeness and the Archimedean property taken together are equivalent to the others."

Comment: Hints: 1. Archimedes' principle gives: there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{x}{\varepsilon}<N.$ 2. Prove by induction that $2^n>n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N.$ Can you proceed ?